# Spell checking VBA sub in MS Access has stopped working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a sub that has been working fine for months, but now, with no change in the code, it has suddenly started erroring out. It's VBA code to spell check the contents of a textbox. Here's the code:

```
Sub SpellCheck(ByRef YourTB As TextBox)

With YourTB
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart = 0
    .SelLength = Len(YourTB)
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart = 0
    .SelLength = 0
End With

End Sub
```

And the error I get is:
Error 2046 - the command or action 'Spelling' isn't available now.

As I say, it was working fine before, but now has suddenly stopped working for all users of the DB. My Google search has only brought up a few reports of this, none with a solution that I can find.

FYI this Access via Microsoft 365 E3 subscription, all PCs on Win10.

Any ideas? And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have figured out what was wrong, so posting here in case it helps anyone else.

It transpired that the forms recordsource (a query) had been amended, and was read-only. It appears having a read-only recordsource won't allow the spell check to run (as presumably you can't change the data).

The query was not meant to be read-only, but it hadn't been spotted as a problem as the data that was being amended on the form was not linked to the query.

Adjusting the query so that it wasn't read-only allowed spell-check to run again.